# How to read a javascript array and reformat it as JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, google-analytics

I'm getting following data from Google Analytics API according to my given parameters. This is a JavaScript array object.

```
[ [ '201801', '(Other)', '129' ],
  [ '201801', 'Direct', '2236' ],
  [ '201801', 'Email', '2' ],
  [ '201801', 'Organic Search', '6263' ],
  [ '201801', 'Referral', '185' ],
  [ '201801', 'Social', '669' ],
  [ '201802', '(Other)', '371' ],
  [ '201802', 'Direct', '2037' ],
  [ '201802', 'Email', '3' ],
  [ '201802', 'Organic Search', '5790' ],
  [ '201802', 'Referral', '162' ],
  [ '201802', 'Social', '515' ],
  [ '201803', '(Other)', '213' ],
  [ '201803', 'Direct', '2465' ],
  [ '201803', 'Organic Search', '8596' ],
  [ '201803', 'Referral', '238' ],
  [ '201803', 'Social', '356' ],
  [ '201804', '(Other)', '65' ],
  [ '201804', 'Direct', '1872' ],
  [ '201804', 'Email', '1' ],
  [ '201804', 'Organic Search', '9275' ],
  [ '201804', 'Referral', '170' ],
  [ '201804', 'Social', '307' ],
  [ '201805', '(Other)', '35' ],
  [ '201805', 'Direct', '2429' ],
  [ '201805', 'Email', '2' ],
  [ '201805', 'Organic Search', '8995' ],
  [ '201805', 'Referral', '234' ],
  [ '201805', 'Social', '341' ],
  [ '201806', 'Direct', '51' ],
  [ '201806', 'Organic Search', '282' ],
  [ '201806', 'Referral', '1' ],
[ '201806', 'Social', '3' ] ]
```

If is not clear at all, please check this GIST : https://gist.github.com/chanakaDe/3ad4e2a51c99386a2737b65a82f034b1

In this array, you can see '201801' like this. It means YEAR is 2018 and MONTH is 1st. It continues likewise.

Normally for one specific month, we are getting 6 values like (Other) , Direct , Email , Organic Search . Referral and Social. In this array, same date is repeating 6 times.

What I want to do is create a simple JSON object out of this. This is the format I want to create in order to display all these data in my AngularJS front end.

```
[
    {
        "date" : "201801",
        "(Other)" : "129",
        "Direct" : "2236",
        "Email" : "2",
        "OrganicSearch" : "6263",
        "Referral" : "185",
        "Social" : "669"
    },
    {
        "date" : "201802",
        "(Other)" : "371",
        "Direct" : "2037",
        "Email" : "3",
        "OrganicSearch" : "5790",
        "Referral" : "162",
        "Social" : "515"
    }
]
```

I want a JSON array like this. I tried to find duplicate values and then tried to merge them into one JSON object if near by elements same. Many attempts like this. But still no good. Please guys, really wanna your help at this moment. I'm not good for data analytics and these kind of sorting things. HELP me please. This project is done using Node.js 8.10.0.

Answer (score 8):

You could take the date as key for a hash table and collect all key value pairs. Later get only the value for an array of objects.

```js
var array = [['201801', '(Other)', '129'], ['201801', 'Direct', '2236'], ['201801', 'Email', '2'], ['201801', 'Organic Search', '6263'], ['201801', 'Referral', '185'], ['201801', 'Social', '669'], ['201802', '(Other)', '371'], ['201802', 'Direct', '2037'], ['201802', 'Email', '3'], ['201802', 'Organic Search', '5790'], ['201802', 'Referral', '162'], ['201802', 'Social', '515'], ['201803', '(Other)', '213'], ['201803', 'Direct', '2465'], ['201803', 'Organic Search', '8596'], ['201803', 'Referral', '238'], ['201803', 'Social', '356'], ['201804', '(Other)', '65'], ['201804', 'Direct', '1872'], ['201804', 'Email', '1'], ['201804', 'Organic Search', '9275'], ['201804', 'Referral', '170'], ['201804', 'Social', '307'], ['201805', '(Other)', '35'], ['201805', 'Direct', '2429'], ['201805', 'Email', '2'], ['201805', 'Organic Search', '8995'], ['201805', 'Referral', '234'], ['201805', 'Social', '341'], ['201806', 'Direct', '51'], ['201806', 'Organic Search', '282'], ['201806', 'Referral', '1'], ['201806', 'Social', '3']],
    result = Object.values(
        array.reduce((r, [date, key, value]) => {
            r[date] = r[date] || { date };
            r[date][key] = value;
            return r;
        }, {})
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer buddy

Answer (score 2):

here you have a working solution and it is easy to read.

```js
var example = [
  ['201801', '(Other)', '129'],
  ['201801', 'Direct', '2236'],
  ['201801', 'Email', '2'],
  ['201801', 'Organic Search', '6263'],
  ['201801', 'Referral', '185'],
  ['201801', 'Social', '669'],
  ['201802', '(Other)', '371'],
  ['201802', 'Direct', '2037'],
  ['201802', 'Email', '3'],
  ['201802', 'Organic Search', '5790'],
  ['201802', 'Referral', '162'],
  ['201802', 'Social', '515'],
  ['201803', '(Other)', '213'],
  ['201803', 'Direct', '2465'],
  ['201803', 'Organic Search', '8596'],
  ['201803', 'Referral', '238'],
  ['201803', 'Social', '356'],
  ['201804', '(Other)', '65'],
  ['201804', 'Direct', '1872'],
  ['201804', 'Email', '1'],
  ['201804', 'Organic Search', '9275'],
  ['201804', 'Referral', '170'],
  ['201804', 'Social', '307'],
  ['201805', '(Other)', '35'],
  ['201805', 'Direct', '2429'],
  ['201805', 'Email', '2'],
  ['201805', 'Organic Search', '8995'],
  ['201805', 'Referral', '234'],
  ['201805', 'Social', '341'],
  ['201806', 'Direct', '51'],
  ['201806', 'Organic Search', '282'],
  ['201806', 'Referral', '1'],
  ['201806', 'Social', '3']
]
//using a forEach to map to object and then a map to map it into an array.
var obj = {};
example.forEach(item => {
  if (obj[item[0]]) {
    obj[item[0]][item[1]] = item[2]
  } else {
    obj[item[0]] = {};
    obj[item[0]]["date"] = item[0]
  }
})

var result = Object.keys(obj).map(k => obj[k])
console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is working, but '(Other)' column is missing. Why is that bro ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can get your desired output -

```js
let data = [
  ['201801', '(Other)', '129'],
  ['201801', 'Direct', '2236'],
  ['201801', 'Email', '2'],
  ['201801', 'Organic Search', '6263'],
  ['201801', 'Referral', '185'],
  ['201801', 'Social', '669'],
  ['201802', '(Other)', '371'],
  ['201802', 'Direct', '2037'],
  ['201802', 'Email', '3'],
  ['201802', 'Organic Search', '5790'],
  ['201802', 'Referral', '162'],
  ['201802', 'Social', '515'],
  ['201803', '(Other)', '213'],
  ['201803', 'Direct', '2465'],
  ['201803', 'Organic Search', '8596'],
  ['201803', 'Referral', '238'],
  ['201803', 'Social', '356'],
  ['201804', '(Other)', '65'],
  ['201804', 'Direct', '1872'],
  ['201804', 'Email', '1'],
  ['201804', 'Organic Search', '9275'],
  ['201804', 'Referral', '170'],
  ['201804', 'Social', '307'],
  ['201805', '(Other)', '35'],
  ['201805', 'Direct', '2429'],
  ['201805', 'Email', '2'],
  ['201805', 'Organic Search', '8995'],
  ['201805', 'Referral', '234'],
  ['201805', 'Social', '341'],
  ['201806', 'Direct', '51'],
  ['201806', 'Organic Search', '282'],
  ['201806', 'Referral', '1'],
  ['201806', 'Social', '3']
];

let output = {};
data.map((value) => { if(!output[value[0]]) { output[value[0]] = {}; } output[value[0]][value[1]] = value[2]; })

console.log(Object.keys(output).map(key => { output[key]["date"] = key; return output[key]; }));
```

Comment: This is an inappropriate use of `map`.  `let output = {}; data.map(value => /* do something to output */)` is better expressed as `let output = data.reduce((output, value) => /* do something to output and return it */, {})`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and effort Vivek

Comment: Still i'm confused how you did this in one signal line :-)

Comment: Using this : data.map((value) => { if(!output[value[0]]) { output[value[0]] = {}; } output[value[0]][value[1]] = value[2]; })      ---> Can you please explain me only if u can.... Sorry for asking it. I know it's too much. :-)

Comment: @ChanakaDeSilva so if you look at output of that it will just use one item in array at a time - `['201806', 'Social', '3']` checks where date is already there or not in `output` and if present then just add `Social: 3` in object with `201806` as key. And in second statement `Object.keys...` it just add key `201806` into its own object like `{ date:201806,  Social: 3 }`. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If `ary` is your input array, this should do it:

```
const outputObj = ary.reduce((obj, subAry) => {
  const [date, key, val] = subAry 
  obj[date] = obj[date] || {}
  obj[date]['date'] = date
  obj[date][key] = val
  return obj
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(outputObj))
```

Answer (score 1):

Group the input data by month with `reduce` with key as date, and map the groupped object to the required output:

```
const data = [ [ '201801', '(Other)', '129' ],
  [ '201801', 'Direct', '2236' ],
  [ '201801', 'Email', '2' ],
  [ '201801', 'Organic Search', '6263' ],
  [ '201801', 'Referral', '185' ],
  [ '201801', 'Social', '669' ],
  [ '201802', '(Other)', '371' ],
  [ '201802', 'Direct', '2037' ],
  [ '201802', 'Email', '3' ],
  [ '201802', 'Organic Search', '5790' ],
  [ '201802', 'Referral', '162' ],
  [ '201802', 'Social', '515' ],
  [ '201803', '(Other)', '213' ],
  [ '201803', 'Direct', '2465' ],
  [ '201803', 'Organic Search', '8596' ],
  [ '201803', 'Referral', '238' ],
  [ '201803', 'Social', '356' ],
  [ '201804', '(Other)', '65' ],
  [ '201804', 'Direct', '1872' ],
  [ '201804', 'Email', '1' ],
  [ '201804', 'Organic Search', '9275' ],
  [ '201804', 'Referral', '170' ],
  [ '201804', 'Social', '307' ],
  [ '201805', '(Other)', '35' ],
  [ '201805', 'Direct', '2429' ],
  [ '201805', 'Email', '2' ],
  [ '201805', 'Organic Search', '8995' ],
  [ '201805', 'Referral', '234' ],
  [ '201805', 'Social', '341' ],
  [ '201806', 'Direct', '51' ],
  [ '201806', 'Organic Search', '282' ],
  [ '201806', 'Referral', '1' ],
[ '201806', 'Social', '3' ] ];

const dataObj = data.reduce((all, [month, key, val]) => {

  if (!all.hasOwnProperty(month)) all[month] = {};
  all[month][key] = val;
  return all;

}, {});

const result = Object.keys(dataObj).map(k => Object.assign({}, dataObj[k], {date: k}))

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const input = [ 
  [ '201801', '(Other)', '129' ],
  [ '201801', 'Direct', '2236' ],
  [ '201801', 'Email', '2' ],
  [ '201801', 'Organic Search', '6263' ],
  [ '201801', 'Referral', '185' ],
  [ '201801', 'Social', '669' ],
  [ '201802', '(Other)', '371' ],
  [ '201802', 'Direct', '2037' ],
  [ '201802', 'Email', '3' ],
  [ '201802', 'Organic Search', '5790' ],
  [ '201802', 'Referral', '162' ],
  [ '201802', 'Social', '515' ],
  [ '201803', '(Other)', '213' ],
  [ '201803', 'Direct', '2465' ],
  [ '201803', 'Organic Search', '8596' ],
  [ '201803', 'Referral', '238' ],
  [ '201803', 'Social', '356' ],
  [ '201804', '(Other)', '65' ],
  [ '201804', 'Direct', '1872' ],
  [ '201804', 'Email', '1' ],
  [ '201804', 'Organic Search', '9275' ],
  [ '201804', 'Referral', '170' ],
  [ '201804', 'Social', '307' ],
  [ '201805', '(Other)', '35' ],
  [ '201805', 'Direct', '2429' ],
  [ '201805', 'Email', '2' ],
  [ '201805', 'Organic Search', '8995' ],
  [ '201805', 'Referral', '234' ],
  [ '201805', 'Social', '341' ],
  [ '201806', 'Direct', '51' ],
  [ '201806', 'Organic Search', '282' ],
  [ '201806', 'Referral', '1' ],
  [ '201806', 'Social', '3' ]
];

let output = [];

for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    let index = output.findIndex(obj => obj.date === input[i][0]);
    if (index === -1) {
        index = output.length;
        output[index] = {date: input[i][0]};
    }
    output[index][input[i][1]] = input[i][2];
}
```